# Neo4j - trouble with multi level hierarchies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following structure in Neo4j:

[Neo Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSLrL.jpg)

The business rules are such that:

Manager 1 MANAGES team leader 1 and team leader 2

Team Leader 1 MANAGES salesperson 1, 2 and 3

Team Leader 2 MANAGES salesperson 4, 5 and 6

Salesperson 4 MANAGES salesperson 7

Salesperson 1 OWNS broker 1

Salesperson 2 OWNS broker 2

Salesperson 3 OWNS broker 3

Salesperson 5 OWNS broker 5

Salesperson 6 OWNS broker 6

Salesperson 7 OWNS broker 4

Broker 1 is a BROKER_ON application 1

Broker 2 is a BROKER_ON application 2

Broker 3 is a BROKER_ON application 3

Broker 4 is a BROKER_ON applications 4 and 5

Broker 5 is a BROKER_ON application 6

Broker 6 is a BROKER_ON application 7

I am struggling with the cypher query so that:

Manager 1 should return applications 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7

Team leader 1 should return applications 1, 2 and 3

Team leader 2 should return applications 4, 5, 6, and 7

Salesperson 1 should return application 1

Salesperson 2 should return application 2

Salesperson 3 should return application 3

Salesperson 4 should return applications 4 and 5

Salesperson 5 should return application 6

Salesperson 6 should return application 7

Salesperson 7 should return applications 4 and 5

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards,

Craig

Comment: What is the exact question, and what have you already tried?

Comment: If I match on Manager 1, for example, how do I traverse my way down to return applications 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7? Similarly, if I were to match on Salesperson 4, how do I return applications 4 and 5 even though he does not own the broker on those applications? I'm very new to Neo4j, so far I have not got much beyond returning the top level Manager or Salesperson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, I will assume that all managers, leaders, and salespeople are represented by nodes with a `Person` label. (The nodes can also have `Manager`, `Leader`, and `SalesPerson` labels, as appropriate, but that is not required for the purposes of this answer.)

To get a collection of all the `Application` nodes for the `Person` with an `id` of 123, you'd just have to use this simple query:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: 123})-[*]->(a:Application)
RETURN p, COLLECT(a) AS apps;
```

The query relies on the variable length relationship pattern `[*]` to match any path length (of at least 1).